How to configure Expo to support sharing multiple images (Photos) with an iOS app?
I’m building an Expo-managed iOS app and need to allow my app to accept multiple images shared directly from Apple Photos via the iOS Share Sheet.
I use eas build --platform ios --profile development to test the app on a real device (not via the Expo Go app) so that new features are supported.

Current Behavior:

When I share one image from Apple Photos, my app appears in the Share Sheet and works correctly.
However, when I select two or more images, my app disappears from the Share Sheet list.


Configuration:
Here’s my app.config.js:
import { ExpoConfig, ConfigContext } from "@expo/config";
import { version } from "./package.json";

const IS_DEV = process.env.APP_VARIANT === "development";

export default ({ config }: ConfigContext): ExpoConfig => ({
  ...config,
  name: IS_DEV ? "Calorily Debug" : "Calorily",
  slug: "calorily",
  version: version,
  orientation: "portrait",
  ios: {
    bundleIdentifier: "com.calorily.app",
    supportsTablet: true,
    usesAppleSignIn: true,
    infoPlist: {
      CFBundleDocumentTypes: [
        {
          CFBundleTypeName: "Images",
          LSHandlerRank: "Alternate",
          LSItemContentTypes: ["public.image", "public.jpeg", "public.png"],
          CFBundleTypeRole: "Viewer",
          LSSupportsMultipleItems: true,
        },
      ],
      NSExtensionActivationRule: {
        NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount: 10,
      },
      NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription:
        "This app accesses your photos to analyze your meals.",
      LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace: true,
      UISupportsDocumentBrowser: true,
      UTImportedTypeDeclarations: [
        {
          UTTypeIdentifier: "com.calorily.app",
          UTTypeTagSpecification: {
            "public.mime-type": "image/*",
            "public.filename-extension": ["jpg", "jpeg", "png"],
          },
          LSHandlerRank: "Alternate",
          CFBundleTypeRole: "Viewer",
          LSSupportsMultipleItems: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    [
      "expo-image-picker",
      {
        photosPermission: "This app accesses your photos to analyze your meal.",
        cameraPermission: "This app accesses your camera to analyze your meal.",
      },
    ],
  ],
});


Goal:

Ensure my app can appear in the iOS Share Sheet when selecting multiple images (up to 10).
Properly receive and process the shared images.


What I’ve Tried:

Adding NSExtensionActivationRule to support up to 10 images.
Specifying CFBundleDocumentTypes with "LSSupportsMultipleItems": true.
Confirmed that my app works fine when one image is shared.


Issue:

My app does not appear in the Share Sheet when selecting two or more images.
Is there something missing in my configuration or limitations with Expo for handling multiple files?


Additional Details:

I am testing with eas build --platform ios --profile development (not with the Expo Go app).
My app uses the Expo Managed Workflow.
I have attached screenshots showing the behavior when one image is shared (app appears) vs. multiple images (app disappears).


